# Correct way of providing access key and secret key in CloudwatchClient in aws php sdk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, sdk

Please provide a Correct way of providing *access key* and *secret key* in **CloudwatchClient** in aws php sdk. I am providing it as:

```
$client = CloudWatchClient::factory(array(
         'key' => $accessKey,
         'secret' => $secretKey,
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
        'version' => 'latest'
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct way of doing it is:

```
$client = CloudWatchClient::factory(array(
        'credentials' => array(
                'key' => $accessKey,
                'secret' => $secretKey
        ),
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
        'version' => 'latest'
    ));
```